# Annotation-specified bean name conflicts with existing error but only in gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty, gradle

I'm trying to deploy an application which works fine using run-jetty-run in eclipse. However if I try to deploy it in gradle with gradlew jettyRun it throws this error

> Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'NRRDaoImpl' for bean class [au.com.xxx.sssbt.NRL.dao.impl.NRRDaoImpl] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [au.com.xxx.sssb.dao.impl.NRRDaoImpl]

au.com.xxx.sssb.dao.impl.NRRDaoImpl does not exist in my code

I have a previous version which works. I believe the only addition was adding @Schedule to the code.

Thanks

Comment: post applicationContext.xml.

Comment: From which directory? There are a few

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why but gradlew clean jettyRun worked...